# How do you Create a Disk from from a MemoryStream (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, filesystems, memorystream

I'm working on a project in VB.Net (2010) where I'm extracting files from an Document Management System.

The Files reside on the network, and information about the files are in a SQL 2005 Database and have been encrypted with the Encryption Stream (System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged)

I have retrieved the file, and decrypted them, but I'm trying to find out how to write the stream back to a file.  I know the file type (which is stored in a SQL DB)

I can't find a solution in any of the VB files or the MS site.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know where on disk you want to save this file? If so, edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 4):

To write a `MemoryStream` to a file just use the `WriteTo` method.

```
Using ms As MemoryStream = GetDecryptedMemoryStreamFromNetworkFile("network_file_path_goes here")
  Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenWrite("new_file_path_goes_here")
    ms.WriteTo(fs)
  End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 (obvious) is to create a temporary file on the disk.

Option 2 is to take something like our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) product, which lets you do exactly what you need and many of our customers use it for scenarios like yours, i.e. represent data taken from document management systems and similar storages.